# Trouble retrieving data from Pocket API using jquery.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, pocket

I'm attempting to retrieve data from my Pocket account using the Pocket API by accessing it with a jQuery post function.  I have obtained the consumer key and access token and when I execute the following code I get a parseerror ...but the data shows up in JSON format in Firebug.

```
var myPost = $.post("https://getpocket.com/v3/get",
    {   "consumer_key": "<<consumer key here>>",
        "access_token": "<<access token here>>",
        "count": "3",
        "detailType": "simple"
    },function(data) {
        return data
    },
    "jsonp");
myPost.done(function( msg ) {
    console.log(myPost)
    alert(msg);

});
myPost.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    console.log(jqXHR)
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

If I change the dataType on the post call from "jsonp" to "json" I don't get the parse error but instead get a generic error (literally just "error") with nothing returned in teh response tab in Firebug.

Attempts to do this call using jQuery.ajax() have also failed, yielding an error 400.

```
var something = $.ajax({
    "accepts": 'application/json',
    "type": 'POST',
    "url": "https://getpocket.com/v3/get",
    "contentType": 'application/json; charset=UTF8',
    "data": {"consumer_key": "<<insert consumer key here>>",
             "access_token": "<<insert access token here>>",
             "count": "3",
             "detailType": "simple"},
    "dataType": 'json',
    "success": ""
 });
```

Seems like I am close using $.post() but how to I clear that error so I can get the actual response data returned?